# How to add offset material-ui Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a small 'Item added' popup dialog on material-ui using it's Grid system. But i can't figure out how to add offset to the Grid. I'm trying to achieve something similar to Bootstrap's `col-sm-10 offset-1` using

`<Grid container justify='center' alignItems='center' item xs={10}>`

But it doesn't work. My solution was to add an empty column before and after my content, like:

```
<Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
<Grid item xs={10} justify='center' alignItems='center'>Content</Grid>
<Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
```

Do I have to do it like this? I can't figure out why justify and alignItems are not working.
Here is the code on codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/item-added-jx9ri

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked the sandbox, you needed to add some properties to your container as opposed to using ghost grid items.

please see here https://codesandbox.io/s/item-added-forked-kv9qw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I believe this is the desired effect you are looking for

Comment: Would be nice if you explained what you did or changed.

Answer (score 8):

the best way I found this solution is as follows.

```
<Grid container>
    {/* offset grid with column you want to offset */}
    <Grid item lg={6} md={6} sm={6}/>
    {/* main grid column! */}
    <Grid item lg={6} md={6} sm={6}>
        I am offset column!.
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Material UI v5 now has an improved grid component called `Grid2`. Using Grid2, in order to get rid of the column before, you can use the `xsOffset` prop like so:

```
<Grid2 xs={10} xsOffset={1} justify='center' alignItems='center'>Content</Grid2>
```

Note that I didn't pass the `item` prop as Grid2 treats its grids as items by default unless you specify they should be treated as containers by passing the `container` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a box with margin (mx) or padding px where x is horizontal. In my opinion this is better than introducing more css classes and properties that need maintenance.

```
  <Grid item xs={12}>
  <Box px={4}>
    <Button fullWidth className={classes.button} variant="contained">
      Continuar Comprando
    </Button>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: px gives padding in pixels, whereas offset is used in terms of grid columns. So, here, it applies only 4 pixels pf padding, not give 4 columns of offset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align a button to the right, all you have to do is set the container justifyContent to flex-end, like this:

```
<Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
```